# Progressbar con jquery en consultas usando ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy en un formulario donde hago una consulta por fecha, esos parámetros los paso por ajax, lo que hace es pasarlo a un controlador para generar un listado.

Sería algo así:

```
 $.ajax ({
 url: './consultar',
 type: 'get',
 data:{fechadesde:$fechadesde, fechahasta:$fechahasra},
 dataType:'html',

Success: function (data)
{
   $mostrarlista.html(data);
},
Error: function (xhr)
{
  Console.log(xhr.resposivetext);
}


 });
```

Lo que necesito es saber si existe algo que me permita obtener algún dato para poder alimentar el progressbar

Ahorita logré fue hacer un beforeSend que de cierta forma me permite mostrar una imagen gif mientras estoy haciendo la consulta.

Mi funcion completa es esta:

```
$buscarpor.change(function(){

$buscar.off();/*Se elimina el evento clic al hacer change ya que esta dentro de
               un evento repetitivo, en este caso se va acumulando y por ello repite el evento
               El evento clic funcionara de nuevo ya que abajo se esta asigando con el on*/
 var $opcion=$buscarpor.val();

   /*Este Switch hace que la vista todopedidos sea completamnete adaptatiba ademas de hacer validacion de los campos
   * y buscara en la base de datos para lista*/

   limpiarCambiar();

   switch ($opcion)
   {

       /*Validar y buscar fecha*/
       case '1':
           $curriertienda.hide();
           $ordenreferencia.hide();
           $fechad.show();
           $btnbuscar.show();
           $fecha.attr('class','col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8');
           $btnbuscar.attr('class','col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4');

           $buscar.on("click",function(){


           $.ajax
           ({
               url:'./validarConsulta',
               type:'get',
               dataType:'json',
               data:{fechadesde:$fechadesde.val(),fechahasta:$fechahasta.val(),opcion:$opcion},


               success: function (data)
               {
                   var $bandera=data.bandera;
                   if($bandera===1)
                   {
                       location.reload();
                       limpiar();

                   }
                   else
                   if(validarFecha($fechadesde.val(),$fechahasta.val())===1)
                   {
                       alert("El campo fecha desde es mayor que el campo fecha hasta");
                   }
                   else {
                       $alert.hide();

                       $.ajax
                       ({
                           xhr: function () {
                               //Creamos el xhr
                               var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                               //Añadimos el evento upload
                               xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                       //El porcentaje completado será lo subido entre el total
                                       var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                       console.log(percentComplete);
                                       //Actualizamos la barra de JQuery-UI
                                       $( ".progressbar" ).progressbar("value",percentComplete*100);
                                       $(".ui-progressbar-value").html(Math.round(percentComplete*100) + '%');
                                       //Actualizamos el div
                                       $('.progress').css({
                                           width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                                       });
                                       if (percentComplete === 1) {
                                           $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                                       }
                                   }
                               }, false);
                               xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                       var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                       console.log(percentComplete);
                                       $( ".progressbar" ).progressbar("value",percentComplete*100);
                                       $(".ui-progressbar-value").html(Math.round(percentComplete*100) + '%');
                                       $('.progress').css({
                                           width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                                       });

                                   }
                               }, false);
                               return xhr;
                           },
                          url:'./consultarPedidos',
                          type:'get',
                          data:{opcion:$opcion,fechadesde:$fechadesde.val(),fechahasta:$fechahasta.val()},
                          dataType:'html',
                           beforeSend: function () {
                              $cargando.show();

                           },
                           complete: function () {
                              $cargando.hide();

                           },

                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               $mostrarpedidos.html(data);

                           },
                           error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                           {
                               alert("Hubo un error por favor revise la consola");
                               console.log(xhr.responseText);
                               console.log(thrownError);
                           }

                       });

                   }

               },
               error: function(xhr)
               {
                   alert("Hubo un error por favor revise la consola");
                   console.log(xhr.responseText);

               }
           });

           });
           break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para crear una progressbar lo ideal es utilizar la interfaz xhr ([XMLHttpRequest](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)):

> xhr (default: ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest
>   otherwise) Type: Function() Callback for creating the XMLHttpRequest
>   object. Defaults to the ActiveXObject when available (IE), the
>   XMLHttpRequest otherwise. Override to provide your own implementation
>   for XMLHttpRequest or enhancements to the factory.

Te pongo un [ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/z7pcx136/) con dos barras de progreso (una hecha con un div y otra utilizando la `progressbar` de [jquery-ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

[Más info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Saludos @Kiko_L lo que me has propuesto no me ha funcionado...y eso mismo que me has pasado lo he leido en un sin fin de foros pero no tengo idea de el porque no funciona. te voy a agregar el codigo que tengo en un comentario mas abajo para que veas todo lo que tengo

Comment: Bien @Kiko_L edite el comentario inicial para que veas te explico un poco para que entiendas de que va, sucede que es un select que adaptativo y se acomoda de acuerdo a lo que yo quiera buscar, ya que al despelgar el select tengo varias opciones para buscar, en este caso te estoy mostrando el case 1: que es buscar desde una fecha hasta otra, bien como veras hago un primer ajax ese ajax es para validar la informacion de que los campos fechas no vayan vacios, como podras ver si todo va bien, entonces voy a un segundo ajax que va contra el servidor, ejecuta el select en la BD y listo en una tabla

Comment: Alli com veras he agregado el objeto xhr, y he agregado para probar las barra de jquery UI y la barra de progreso HTML solo para probar, pero no courre absolutamente nada. Lo que ves alli en beforeSent y Complete  era busando una alternativa y que muestro un gif que dice cargando mientras ocurre la consulta, pero quiero lograr de alguna forma lo del progress bar

Comment: No he podido probar pero ¿puede ser que el problema que el xhr está dentro del "success"?. No sé exactamente cuándo quieres mostrar la barra de progreso, pero ten en cuenta que ese código se ejecutará sólo cuando termine la llamada correctamente.

Comment: Saludos, bueno esta dentro de un success porque ese success pertenece a un ajax de validación, si todo funciona bien se ejecuta el segundo ajax y por ello es que lo he colocado en el segundo ajax que en este caso ese seria el ajax de consulta, crees que existe una mejor forma de hacerlo? Es decir necesito esos dos ajax pero existe una mejor forma de hacerlo para poder usar el progresa bar?